# Практика перевод XML в JS-объект - где подправить код?

Tags: xmlparser

Вот практикуюсь. Не могу собрать код

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
// console.log('parser', parser);

const xmlString = `
<list>
  <student>
    <name lang="en">
      <first>Ivan</first>
      <second>Ivanov</second>
    </name>
    <age>35</age>
    <prof>teacher</prof>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name lang="ru">
      <first>Петр</first>
      <second>Петров</second>
    </name>
    <age>58</age>
    <prof>driver</prof>
  </student>
</list>
`;
// console.log('xmlString', xmlString)

const xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

const listNode = xmlDOM.querySelector("list");
const studentNode = listNode.querySelectorAll("student");
const nameNode = listNode.querySelector("name");
const firstNode = listNode.querySelector("first");
const secondNode = listNode.querySelector("second");
const ageNode = listNode.querySelector("age");
const profNode = listNode.querySelector("prof");
// console.log('listNode', listNode);
// console.log('studentNode', studentNode);
// console.log('nameNode', nameNode);
// console.log('firstNode', firstNode);
// console.log('secondNode', secondNode);
// console.log('ageNode', ageNode);
// console.log('profNode', profNode);

const langAttr = nameNode.getAttribute('lang');
// console.log('langAttr', langAttr);

// studentNode.forEach(student => console.log('result', result));
studentNode.forEach(studentNode => xmlString);

const result = {
  list: [ {
  prof: profNode.textContent,
  first: firstNode.textContent,
  second: secondNode.textContent,
  lang: langAttr,
  age: Number(ageNode.textContent),
  }
 ]
};
console.log('result', result);
```

Результат вывода в консоли:

```
"result" Object {
  list: [Object {
  age: 35,
  first: "Ivan",
  lang: "en",
  prof: "teacher",
  second: "Ivanov"
}]
}
```

Только один студент получается, не могу понять, как написать forEach для перебора студентов и языка. Так же результат хотелось бы получить в таком виде:

JS-объект:

```
{
  list: [
    { name: 'Ivan Ivanov', age: 35, prof: 'teacher', lang: 'en' },
    { name: 'Петр Петров', age: 58, prof: 'driver', lang: 'ru' },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так думаю

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
// console.log('parser', parser);

const xmlString = `
<list>
  <student>
    <name lang="en">
      <first>Ivan</first>
      <second>Ivanov</second>
    </name>
    <age>35</age>
    <prof>teacher</prof>
  </student>
  <student>
    <name lang="ru">
      <first>Петр</first>
      <second>Петров</second>
    </name>
    <age>58</age>
    <prof>driver</prof>
  </student>
</list>
`;
// console.log('xmlString', xmlString)

const xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

const listNode = xmlDOM.querySelector("list");
const studentNodes = [...listNode.querySelectorAll("student")];
const list = [];
studentNodes.forEach( studentNode => {
  
  const nameNode = studentNode.querySelector("name");
  const langAttr = nameNode.getAttribute('lang');
  const firstNode = studentNode.querySelector("first");
  const secondNode = studentNode.querySelector("second");
  const ageNode = studentNode.querySelector("age");
  const profNode = studentNode.querySelector("prof");
  list.push({
    prof: profNode.textContent,
    first: firstNode.textContent,
    second: secondNode.textContent,
    lang: langAttr,
    age: Number(ageNode.textContent),
  });
});

const result = {
  list: list
};
console.log('result', result);
```